# QMetaObject::newInstance failes if type is in namespace

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmetaobject

I want to create a new instance of class `A` that inherits a base class derived from `QObject`.

In case `A` isn't in a namespace this works fine, but in case `A` is in a namespace this call returns a null pointer:

```
QObject *o = metaObject->newInstance(arg1,arg2,arg3);
```

The `metaObject` itself returns the correct class name (including the namespace)

```
std::cout << "Class name from staticMetaObject: " << metaObject->className() << std::endl;
```

The constructor of `A` is marked with `Q_INVOKABLE`. How can I use `QMetaObject::newInstance` with namespaces?

Comment: Docs say: "_This class is not normally required for application programming_". So probably you shouldn't use `QMetaObject` in your application programming.

Comment: Can you paste more code related to your classes?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto And how is that supposed to be helpful? I use `QMetaObject` all the time. You paid for it, use it!

Comment: @KubaOber Sometimes people because of their poorly designed software architecture and planning have to use such functionalities which in many cases they can be avoided and replaced with easier solutions. However, I agree with you, in pro projects using such things is just fine but we should know what we're doing.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto Knowing nothing about the architecture it might be a tad presumptuous to shoot it down. Let's assume that the architecture is OK :)

Answer (score 1):

It definitely works for me under Qt 5.5.1.

Perhaps your base class is missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/ns-meta-35505644
#include <QtCore>

int A_a, B_a;

class A : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Q_INVOKABLE A(int a, QObject * parent = 0) : QObject{parent} {
      A_a = a;
   }
};

namespace NS {
class B : public A {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Q_INVOKABLE B(int a, QObject * parent = 0) : A{a, parent} {
      B_a = a;
   }
};
}

int main() {
   Q_ASSERT(A_a == 0);
   Q_ASSERT(B_a == 0);
   QScopedPointer<QObject> a {A::staticMetaObject.newInstance(Q_ARG(int, 10))};
   Q_ASSERT(A_a == 10);
   QScopedPointer<QObject> b {NS::B::staticMetaObject.newInstance(Q_ARG(int, 20))};
   Q_ASSERT(A_a == 20);
   Q_ASSERT(B_a == 20);
   QScopedPointer<QObject> c {b->metaObject()->newInstance(Q_ARG(int, 30))};
   Q_ASSERT(A_a == 30);
   Q_ASSERT(B_a == 30);
}

#include "main.moc"
```